# Rebinding immutable class attribute in the base class from a derived class

Tags: python

I have this generic problem in python. The base class defines a class attribute `class_attr`. This attribute is immutable, in this case it is a number. I want to change this attribute from a derived class, thus rebinding `Base.class_attr` to the new value (in my toy case, incrementing it).

The question is how to do this without explicitly naming `Base` in statement `Base.class_attr += 1`.

```
class Base(object):
    # class attribute: 
    class_attr = 0

class Derived(Base): 
    @classmethod
    def increment_class_attr(cls):        
        Base.class_attr += 1 
        # is there a solution which does not name the owner of the 
        # class_attr explicitly?

        # This would cause the definition of Derived.class_attr, 
        # thus Base.class_attr and Derived.class_attr would be 
        # two independent attributes, no more in sync:
    #   cls.class_attr += 1

Derived.increment_class_attr()
Derived.increment_class_attr()

print Base.class_attr # 2
```

**Please note**: I am after the very question, that is, can I rebind the attributes of a parent class. I am not after the work-around solutions to this problem (e.g., shift `increment_class_attr` to Base).

Answer (score 1):

Use the `__bases__` attribute:

```
In [68]: class Base(object):
    ...:     # class attribute: 
    ...:     class_attr = 0
    ...:     

In [69]: class Derived(Base):
    ...:     @classmethod
    ...:     def inc(cls):
    ...:         p, = cls.__bases__
    ...:         p.class_attr += 1
    ...:         

In [70]: Base.class_attr
Out[70]: 0

In [71]: Derived.inc()

In [72]: Derived.inc()

In [73]: Base.class_attr
Out[73]: 2
```

If you have multiple inheritance:

```
In [88]: class DifferentInherited(object):
    ...:     class2_attr = 0
    ...: 


In [90]: class Der2(Base, DifferentInherited):
    ...:     @classmethod
    ...:     def inc(cls):
    ...:         print cls.__bases__
    ...:         a, b, = cls.__bases__
    ...:         print a.class_attr
    ...:         print b.class2_attr
    ...:         

In [91]: Der2.inc()
(<class '__main__.Base'>, <class '__main__.DifferentInherited'>)
2
0
```

Assuming you don't know the inheritance order either, you'll need to test each class for the variable:

```
In [127]: class Der3(DifferentInherited, Base):
     ...:     @classmethod
     ...:     def inc(cls):
     ...:         # This gets a list of *all* classes with the attribute `class_attr`
     ...:         classes = [c for c in cls.__bases__ if 'class_attr' in c.__dict__]
     ...:         for c in classes:
     ...:             c.class_attr += 1
     ...:             

In [128]: Der3.inc()

In [129]: Base.class_attr
Out[129]: 3

In [131]: DifferentInherited.class2_attr
Out[131]: 0
```

And multiple inheritance uses `__mro__`:

```
In [146]: class Multi(Der3):
     ...:     @classmethod
     ...:     def inc(cls):
     ...:         c_attr =  [c for c in cls.__mro__ if 'class_attr' in c.__dict__]
     ...:         print c_attr
     ...:         c_attr[0].class_attr += 1
     ...:         

In [147]: Multi.inc()
[<class '__main__.Base'>]

In [148]: Base.class_attr
Out[148]: 4
```

Comment: Thanks, but this has approximately the same level of maintainability as the original with `Base`. What about if I inherit Derived multiply `Derived(AnotherBase, Base)` or across multiple single inheritance `Derived1(Base)`; `Derived(Derived1)`?

Comment: `__bases__` and `Base` have nothing in common. `__bases__` refers to the inherited classes. It returns a tuple of classes: `p, = cls.__bases__` gets the first one (The first inherited class - in this case, `Base`.

Comment: Yes I understood your code. What I am saying is that when I have another baseclass named `AnotherBase` and declare a derived class `class Derived (AnotherBase, Base)` then your `p` variable will no more refer to `Base` but to `AnotherBase`. However, `AnotherBase` is not the owner of class attribute `class_attr`. Similarly, with chained inheritance, `p` will refer to `Derived1`, not to `Derived`.

Comment: So you want to access the possible `class_attr` value, of a class you have no idea what it might called, and you have no idea what the `mro` inheritance (Inheritance order) is? The only thing I can recommend is testing each class in the mro/bases for whether it has `class_attr` and incrementing the first one you come along - but that's really prone to errors. What exactly are you attempting to do?

Comment: Just trying to get my hands on python ;) Coming from C++. My point is that python **does** resolve `Derived.class_attr` - when I merely print it, it just uses MRO and outputs the value of that attribute if it finds it in some base class. But, apparently I cannot ask python to give me reference to that attribute such that I could re-assign it. As specified in (http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) "Class attribute assignments update the class’s dictionary, never the dictionary of a base class."

Comment: You'd need to check each class for the `class_attr` attribute - added a way to get that.

Comment: Thanks, +1. This does not solve the multiple levels of inheritance, but OK.

Comment: For multiple levels, replace `__bases__` with `__mro__` to get the full inheritance tree. Then go through backwards until you find a class if you just want the topmost level. Added example.